# Invalid Call Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving an error with the below code (Invalid Procedure Call or Argument). I started with a recorded code, and updated the code to allow for variable data. The final line of code is giving the error. The destination sheet is in the workbook, and the table name is not already taken. The variable "LastRow" is defined earlier in the full code, and I confirmed it is pulling the correct value. Any ideas as to what could be causing the error?

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase _

        , SourceData:="'Funding Summary'!A1:AQ" & LastRow, Version:=6)

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Funding Pivot'!A3", TableName:="FundingPivot", _

        DefaultVersion:=6)
```

LastRow variable was defined earlier:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Did you define `LastRow` somewhere and give it a non-zero value?

Comment: Yeah, it's defined early on in the code. I was able to confirm that the variable is working.

Comment: ok, thanks! I've added that for clarity

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I've added that code to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

`Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="'Funding Pivot'!A3"`

Should be

`Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Sheets("Funding Pivot").Range("A3")`